# Ignorar CSS em determinado trecho da página

Tags: html, css

Vamos supor que tenho algum CSS do tipo:

```
#foo input {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* seguem mais um milhão de propriedades */
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

Todo `input` filho de `foo` vai ter todas essas propriedades.

Supondo que no meio da página eu queira que um único `input` não tenha essa formatação... Eu sei que posso dar-lhe uma classe específica ou id específico, com novas regras de formatação. Mas apenas o que eu especificar será sobrescrito. Eu tenho que jogar um valor `initial` em todas as propriedades já especificadas anteriormente para poder desfazê-las todas.

Existe alguma forma mais curta de se ignorar o CSS por apenas um trecho da página? Eu adoraria algo do tipo:

```
<!-- aqui acaba o CSS -->
<input blablabla />
<!-- aqui o CSS começa a valer de novo -->
```

Ou

```
<input blablabla ignoreCss="True"> <!-- seria tão bom se houvesse algo assim -->
```

Ou ainda

```
$("#idDoMeuInput").ignoreCssCompletely();
```

Procurei por várias alternativas em vários lugares, mas não encontrei. Existe alguma forma de fazer um elemento ignorar o CSS?

Comment: Ignorar não. Mas por JavaScript é possível remover todos os estilos de um elemento, só não acho muito prático.

Comment: Voce pode usar iframes, e criar completamente outra pagina fora e inserir ela!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Que tal usar um `:not` para ignorar uma classe específica? Algo assim:

```css
#foo input:not(.ignoreCss) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=foo>
  <input></input>
  <input></input>
  <input class=ignoreCss></input> <!-- Esse não vai ser vermelho -->
  <input></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Não é possível remover/ignorar regras de CSS defenidas fora do elemento (ie na folha de CSS).

Se você tiver `<input style="color: red;">`, aí sim é possível usar o jQuery `$("selector").removeAttr("style");` para remover esse estilo. Mas mesmo aí ele vai remover o local e usar o que esteja defenido no CSS.

Assim a solução é mesmo usar classes ou modificar o `style` no próprio elemento.

Lembre-se que existe também o `!important` para ajudar a fazer override, se necessário.

Answer (score 3):

No seu caso, você pode definir o CSS diretamente no seu `input` em vez de usar a regra para todos `input`.

Opção CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#formulario .input_css  {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9000;
}
-->
</style>

<body>
<div id="formulario">
  <input name="" type="text"   class="input_css"/>
  <input name="input sem css" type="text" />
  <input name="input sem css" type="text" />
  <input name="" type="text" class="input_css" />
  <input name="input sem css" type="text" />
  <input name="" type="text" class="input_css"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você quiser "ignorar" as heranças do CSS estaria perdendo o sentido de cascata. O que é aconselhável fazer e reescrever o css para seu elemento específico e caso a herança persista você adiciona !important, por exemplo: border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
Assim ele "força" aquele elemento receber a formatação css.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez uma classe no css que devolvesse os presets default para esse elemento ajudasse.
Exemplo: Tenho minhas div's todas com bordas "1px solid" e uma delas eu quero sem borda.
Meu css fica assim:

```
div{border: 1px solid;}
.div_sem_css{ border: none; }
```

E meu html:

```
<body>
<div> Div 1</div>
<div> Div 2</div>
<div class="div_sem_css">Div 3</div>
<div> Div 4</div>
</body>
```

A "Div 3" não aplica a borda.
A ideia consiste em criar uma classe css que tenha "valores padrão" e aplicá-la ao que não for receber o css. Deu pra entender mais ou menos? rs