# Ignorar Classe CSS em uma página específica

Tags: css, angularjs

Tenho um sistema onde o front foi feito com `AngularJS`. Nesse sistema tenho a página `index.html` aonde declaro todas as bibliotecas, nessa mesma página tenho

```
o seguinte trecho de código:
<div id="wrapper">
         <hamburger-toggle state="stateModel" id="menu-toggle" href="#menu"></hamburger-toggle>
         <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Tenho uma `div` que tem a classe CSS `wrapper`, e dentro dessa `div` tenho outra onde carrego todas minhas paginas.

O problema é que minha página de login é carregada dentro dessa `div` com a classe `wrapper`, e essa classe desconfigura toda a página. Gostaria de ignorar essa classe apenas na minha página de login.

Tentei fazer isso:

```
#wrapper input:not(.ignoreCss) {...}
```

E no começo da página de login fiz isso:

```
 <div class="ignoreCss">
 ...
```

Porém não funcionou. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: O que seria esse `input` no seu CSS ?

Comment: Então, não entendi também, foi um exemplo que achei de como ignorar uma Classe css em uma parte da página: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14639/ignorar-css-em-determinado-trecho-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Dai tentei implementar mas nada aconteceu kk

Comment: Você usa Jquery?

Comment: Estou usando Angular, não usei nada de Jquery ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Utilizando seu Exemplo**.

Ao você fazer isso: `#wrapper input:not(.ignoreCss) {...}` você está ignorando o css apenas para inputs, e não da página completa. Para eliminar da div completa, você poderia fazer isso:

```css
#wrapper :not(.ignoreCss) {
    background: black;
    border : 1px solid;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>s</div>
  <div class=ignoreCss>f</div> <!-- Esse não vai ser preto -->
  <div>d</div>
</div>
```

Assim você não está limitando apenas à `inputs`.

Nesse código, você está dizendo que a div que possuir a classe **ignoreCss**, não terá as propriedades setadas para o id `#wrapper`.

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/tqzbru0b/1/)