# Ajustar apenas um componente

Tags: css, primefaces

Com este css eu altero todos os `inputs` de meus `autocomplete` :

```
.ui-autocomplete-multiple ul{
    padding:0;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

O problema é que eu preciso aleterar apenas de uma tela e não de todas, como eu posso referenciar para que seja alterado apenas da tela cujo id seja x ou passo um `styleClass` como parâmetro ?

**EDITADO**

Este é o html gerado:

```
<div id="manageEventoPermanenciaNavioForm:pidoS" class="ui-autocomplete-multiple">
  <ul class="ui-autocomplete-multiple-container ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="float:left">
    <li class="ui-autocomplete-input-token"><input id="manageEventoPermanenciaNavioForm:pidoS_input" name="manageEventoPermanenciaNavioForm:pidoS_input" autocomplete="off" type="text"></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="ui-button ui-button-autocomplete ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only" type="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span></button><select id="manageEventoPermanenciaNavioForm:pidoS_hinput" name="manageEventoPermanenciaNavioForm:pidoS_hinput" multiple="multiple" class="ui-helper-hidden"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: O `id` do elemento é encontrado em outras telas?

Comment: Não, apenas em uma tela.

Comment: Você pode exibir os trechos relevantes do HTML?

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade/143893#143893)

Comment: No HTML apresentado não existe a classe `.ui-autocomplete-multiple`. Tem certeza que está certo ou que o CSS está correto?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esqueci de postar a div completa, já corrigido.

Comment: E o que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14639/ignorar-css-em-determinado-trecho-da-p%C3%A1gina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o atributo `styleClass` no seu `p:autoComplete`:

```
<p:autoComplete styleClass="classeEstilo" />
```

Configure sua classe css da seguinte maneira:

```
.classeEstilo ul {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Edite a resposta, a solução é quase é essa, mas como me interessa a `ul`, basta ser `.classeEstilo ul{}`. Eu valido sua resposta :)

Comment: @Douglas o último exemplo era exatamente .classeEstilo ul {}, mas acabei repetindo a resposta de cima. Obrigado pela observação, já ajustei a resposta. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar o elemento por *id* você deve suar `#`:

**HTML:**

```
<input id='id_do_elemento'>
```

**CSS:**

```
#id_do_elemento{
    padding:0;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Dessa forma esse estilo será aplicado somente ao alvo com o identificador específicado.

[Seletores CSS.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Também não funcionou :/

Comment: O problema é que não sei da forma que o autocomplete trata.

Comment: O `id` que você deseja alterar é um `li` da `ul` dentro de .ui-autocomplete-multiple?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar o html gerado pra você me ajudar porque não tenho certeza da resposta.